# Env variables on Google Cloud?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, gcloud

This might be a super noob question but, I deployed an app to gcloud using the console, however once deployed it did not get my .env file so, we have a sign up form on our site linked to mailchimp, however our API keys and list ID are on our .env file, how do I make Google Cloud read this file.

I'm a super newbie on this, so I read the documentation but didn't understand anything. I just know i have a nodeJS backend with a file called server.js using Express and i have a .env file with my API Keys but can't figure out how to make google read those ENV Variables.

Help?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Are you deploying on app engine?

Comment: Yes, I am using an app.yaml file and the gcloud SDK on my console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `app.yaml` file you can provide the env variables and consume in your app code with `process.env.PORT`:

```
runtime: nodejs10
env_variables:
  PORT: 8080
```

Comment: It worked! however even though i add app.yaml to .gitignore it keeps adding it to the commit list, how do i prevent this?

Comment: @DanielContreras it should not happen. See if the path etc is correct

Comment: I found out why, it was already commited before so git kept tracking changes, removed the file from git and eveything is working now. Thank You!